# How can I use closures with function pointers?

Tags: javascript, closures

My goal is to use closures while still writing clean code. One thing I noticed is that somehow I always end up repeating myself because one of my anonymous functions is needed in more than one case.

To this goal, I want to have these repeated functions stored in an object which I can later reuse.

Now, to my question. I've created this example http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoespinha/tTx64/ and the alert will not fire, because `y` is null.

However, if I inline the function, everything works fine http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoespinha/tTx64/1/

Is there a trick to work around this? How can I have it working in the first example? The variable `y` is still there, why can't JS catch it?

Comment: This is exactly how closures work. If you define a function it has access to the scope it was defined in. In this case you want access variable from different scope. In functional programming simplest solution is to make function access this variable via argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want objects having own variables (y) and sharing functions.

What you really need is probably prototype.

```
function Holder() {
   this.y = 5;
   this.myFn();
}
Holder.prototype.myFn = function() {
    alert("The value of the closure var is " + this.y);           
}
new Holder();
```

I'd suggest the reading of [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) so that you don't try to rebuild OOP with just closures.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I suspected what I was doing was not directly possible and I had actually ran into this problem before, but this confirms it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
//our constructor, each instance will carry a y of 5
function Proto() {
    this.y = 5;
}

//a shared function for all instances
Proto.prototype.returnedFn = function() {
    alert("The value of the closure var is " + this.y);
}

//just a wrapper for the new instance call.
//I just like it this way to avoid using "new" when making instances
function newFn() {
    //return a new instance
    return new Proto();
}

//test it out
newFn().returnedFn();
newFn().returnedFn();
```

Comment: Thank you too for also providing the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example would need some kind of **dynamic scoping** to work. Javascript is statically scoped.

Closures allow a function to capture some local variables from the scope it's defined in. `Holder.myFn` isn't defined in a scope that contains variable `y`.

Also note that every instance of a function has its own closure. Hence it's not possible to define your function once and have it refer to different `y`'s in different contexts. (In your second example the inner function is defined *every time* you call `newFn`, so many instances can exist, each with its own copy of `y`.)

Comment: Now it makes sense. The scope is resolved when the function is defined and not when it is executed. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I will also add an answer to my own question to report my findings.

Based on the other solutions provided and partly using the OOP solution, I found another way which also makes use of closures.

```
// Object prototype which takes an argument 
function MyObj(abc) {

    // Declare function using a closure
    // and thus being able to use the argument
    this.myFn = (function(){
        return function() {
            alert("abc is " + abc);
        };
    })();                
}

// Then we can simply create an object with the
// desired argument and the function will behave as expected
var v = new MyObj(10);
v.myFn();
```

I think nobody provided this solution possibly because I omitted that I don't really want to store the values locally in the object. I simply want to pass some values in, make use of them in one function and then get rid of the object.

In this case I believe a pure OOP solution might be overkill.

Anyhow, thank you for all the proposed solutions!​